# SPA, offline online, keep user logged in

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-core, single-page-application, offlineapps

I have a Single Page Application where i want users to be able to stay logged in after closing the browser and starts using the browser again when offline or online. The method I'm using now is including the localStorage where i store a timestamp that indicates how long a user is considered logged in. The problem with this is that the value can easily be tampered with, resulting in users not having to log in at all to use the app. 
   Is there a recommended or proven to work solution for accomplishing this?

Comment: Hi @robbannn - not sure if JWT input helped or not.  You might need to add more detail if not. Please confirm thanks

Answer (score 2):

JWT - JSON Web Tokens - will do the job

Each token has 3 parts

- header (confirming it is indeed a JWT)
- payload (set with user's identity, access rights, expiry date / time
- signature (so no one can mess with it)

In the payload, pay particular attention to the `exp` element, which lets you set the exact time the login expires.

So you can safely save them in local storage.

A few sources for more info:

https://jwt.io/

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token

Comment: Great answer! It's unbelievable that it took 7y to get the first +1